# Page redirect is not perfect work with page content

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

When i  comment a specific post and edit this comment i want to keep remain in this post in the same page but it redirect the Main post Page. How can i solve this provlem.
This is my update comment page code

```
<?php
 require_once('config.php');
 require_once('user_logedin.php');
 ?>
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['c_id'])) {
    header("location:home4.php");
}
else {
    $id = $_REQUEST['c_id'];
    //echo $id;
}
?>

 <?php
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

  $msg = $_POST['editmsg'];
  $update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `newsfeedcomment` SET `comment_body`='$msg' WHERE `comment_id`='$id' LIMIT 1");

  if ($msg) {

   //header("location:home4.php?post_id=.$id");
   header("Location:home4.php?post_id=".$id);
   //header("Location:home4.php");

  }

}
 ?>
```

It's work but don't display the page content

Comment: Shouldn't the last redirect use the query argument `c_id` instead of `post_id`, since the first redirect is checking for `c_id` ?

Comment: get rid of the closing and reopening php-tags. you're producing output here, so the `header` won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1st) do not use `$_REQUEST`; use `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIES` separately, you will avoid problems in the (near) future

2nd) allways call `exit;` after `header("location: ..")`, as the header can be overwrited by some other code

possible answer:

I believe the line `if(!isset($_REQUEST['c_id']))` is the only way to redirect back to home. Are you really sure the `$_REQUEST['c_id']` is set during "update" post? What is your action attribute of your form?

//edit
Based on @sowa suggestion: Aren't you combining post_id and c_id unwillingly?